# When to deploy qminimal.dll

Tags: windows, qt, deployment

I'm using Qt5.  I've seen many questions where people refer to including qminimal.dll alongside qwindows.dll but I've never seen the documentation mention it.

What is qminimal.dll?

When is it appropriate to deploy qminimal.dll with one's application?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the functionality behind qminimal.dll, but regarding your question "When is it appropriate..." the only answer conforming to the docs can be: use windeploy to find out the set of needed files. qminimal.dll may or may not be in it.